# How to use click and value at the same time?

Tags: javascript, forms, function, click, getelementsbyclassname

*I want to enter the radio button and the value at the same time to fill out a form in the browser console.*

**This way it just runs the click event**

```
document.getElementById("email").value = "abcd@mail.com";
document.getElementsByClassName("kSKYRE")[0].click();
```

**When the 2nd function runs, the 1st value is canceled.**

```
function value() {
document.getElementById("email").value = "abcd@mail.com";
}

function radio() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("kSKYRE")[0].click();
  }

  setTimeout(radio, 2000);
  setTimeout(value, 1000);
```

I'm trying to generate a spotify sign up code

[image]

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: If `kSKYRE` is a submit button then the page reloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the event `Click` fire some other events (like a change on radio buttons) try with `checked` like this `document.getElementsByClassName("kSKYRE")[0].checked = true;`

This is a simple test:

```html
<form type="submit">
    <input type="text" id="email" style="width:500px"/>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="colors" id="red" class="kSKYRE">Red<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue" class="kSKYRE">Blue
</form>


<script>
    
    document.getElementById("email").value = "RED - next blu";
    document.getElementsByClassName("kSKYRE")[0].checked = true;
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("email").value = "BLU - next red";
        document.getElementsByClassName("kSKYRE")[1].checked = true;
    }, 2000);
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("email").value = "RED - next change with click: BLU or CLICK/CHANGE ";
        document.getElementsByClassName("kSKYRE")[0].checked = true;
    }, 4000);
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("email").value = "BLU - LAST";
        document.getElementsByClassName("kSKYRE")[1].click();
    }, 8000);
    
    
     document.querySelector("#blue").addEventListener("change", function() {
        document.getElementById("email").value = "CLICK/CHANGE";
    });
    
</script>
```